# Modal with Viewmodel loaded in _Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, viewmodel

I´m facing the following problem:

I have some Modals, that use viewmodels. For example, a LoginModal that validates user input by using a LoginViewModel.

This (next to the other) modal is rendered as PartialView in _Layout.cshtml, because it may be used on any page:

```
...        
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Modals/CartModal.cshtml");
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Modals/LoginModal.cshtml");
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Modals/AccountModal.cshtml");
...
```

My starting page lists events, using an own viewmodel. The problem is, when trying to load the starting page, two @model-statements are loaded and thus the app crashes. Until now all work is done by the HomeController, in the LoginModal I´m using an Ajax.BeginForm.

I´m wondering how to solve this and thought of using a BaseViewModel in _Layout.cshtml, which contains other viewmodels. I would try to access them, for example, in the LoginModal by using

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LoginViewModel.EMail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "EMail", @id = "inputemail" } })
```

Might that be the correct / "best practice" way of solving this problem?

Comment: Use `@Html.Action(...)` in your layout to call server methods that return the partial partial views you want (and you statement that _two @model-statements are loaded and thus the app crashes._ is incorrect - the error is a result of passing the model in the view to the partial which expects a different model

Comment: The alternative is to pass a model to the partial - `Html.RenderPartial("LoginModal", new LoginViewModel());`

Comment: OK, I´ll try that right now, thank you so far!

Comment: Your second answer works like a charm, great and thank you again!